# Session.CFID / CFTOKEN VS Client.CFID / CFTOKEN

Tags: session, coldfusion

Our apps are using client variables management for unique identify a website visitor and eventually store it as the ID of an e-commerce order, for example.

Our customer orders table saves strings like "10000032:98517605:77134665" (cfid+cftoken) as its unique ID.

Now we need to get rid of client variables, so no more "CLIENT.cfid" in our code.

First thing that comes up to my mind is to simply replace that with "SESSION.cfid" and "SESSION.cftoken". But the big doubt is:

Will the generated id and token still be univoque against the existing ones? 
Is it possible that making such a change will result in having "10000032:98517605:77134665" re-generated?

How can I make unique visitor ids, considering existing ones too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would set a new session value `onSessionStart` that you can guarantee would be unique. So in the `onSessionStart` method of Application.cfc, you can set something like:

```
<cfset Session.CustomerID = CreateUUID() />
```

With that, when the session begins, a UUID (guaranteed to be unique) will be put into the session scope. You can then use that for whatever you need. If this needs to be persistent, you could write it out to a cookie as well (since sessions don't persist long term like Client variables do).

Comment: This is great Mr Short but.... can you ensure me it won't create an already created ID?

Comment: CreateUUID() will indeed be unique (as "Mr Short" has indicated) for that server. But I believe it's uniqueness depends on things like OS entropy. So load and clustering are both concerns at some point. If you are using j2ee sessions (the jsessionid;) you will also guarantee uniqueness. Either approach will likely increase your DB field sizes and degrade performance a little :)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "one's annual risk of being hit by a meteorite is estimated to be one chance in 17 billion,[32] that means the probability is about 0.00000000006 (6 × 10−11), equivalent to the odds of creating a few tens of trillions of UUIDs in a year and having one duplicate." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID#Random%5FUUID%5Fprobability%5Fof%5Fduplicates